# About the Chinese translation of two passages in the notes of Laurids Brigge by Rilke

Tags: translation, culture, history, books, literature

According to Bing-AI, the notes of Laurid Brigge by Rilke were translated two times into Chinese (1986 and 2007), cf. screenshot.

I am curious about the translation of two passages for my calligraphic works, namely the first from the 57th chapter:

> Aber demütigen hätte er sich müssen vor ihr in seinem ganzen Staat und schreiben was sie diktiert, mit beiden Händen, wie Johannes auf Patmos, knieend.

and the second from the 16th chapter:

> Es sind jetzt vielleicht dreihundert Leute im Saale, die lesen; aber es ist unmöglich, dass sie jeder einzelne einen Dichter haben. (Weiß Gott, was sie haben.)

If you have one of the translations at hand, feel free to answer. In principle, I am interested in both of the translations, and I am happy to receive an answer with both translations referred to in the AI generated contribution.

If there are even further published translations other than the two the AI found, you can also cite them and deliver the translation of the two passages in these works. I am happy for every answer!

[image: Bing-AI]

Comment: I think AI is outputting nonsense here. The first translator mentioned, 王道乾, is a French translator (https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8E%8B%E9%81%93%E4%B9%BE/7050125). I cannot find evidence of him having ever translated a German book. The second person 李欧梵 is a literary critic and does not translate books at all (https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%9D%8E%E6%AD%90%E6%A2%B5).

Here is an incomplete list of translations of the book in question: https://book.douban.com/works/1023582?order=time

Comment: Thank you for sorting it out! Do I understand it correctly that the books on Douban are behind a paywall. I can't check them by myself, right? To clarify my question, I'm happy with any published translation of the two passages, as long as they are properly cited with the name of the translator. I'm not focused on a specific translator and the AI response was only to show my research effort. In fact, if you have any translation of the notes at hand, feel free to answer! @user2249675

Comment: Douban is a website for collecting book metadata. I don't have copies of these books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few copies, translated by 陈早, 林克, 曹元勇

First passage:

> 陈早: 纵使华服加身，诗人在它面前也要谦恭克己，他要像帕特莫斯岛上的约翰那样，跪着用双手写出它传授的东西。

> 林克: 但本来他必须在他的冠冕堂皇中对她卑躬屈膝并记录她所口授的，用两只手，像约翰在拔摩岛上，跪着。

> 曹元勇: 然而，不管诗人的气度如何非凡庄重，面对贝蒂娜的爱，他都应该谦恭地跪在她面前，用双手把她的口授记录下来，就像使徒约翰在帕忒莫斯记录上帝的启示那样。

Second passage:

> 陈早: 在大厅里可能有300个在读书的人；但不可能每个人都拥有一位诗人。（上帝知道他们拥有什么。）

> 林克: 大厅里现在也许有三百人，他们在阅读；但这是不可能的，他们每一个人都拥有一位诗人。（天知道他们有什么。）

> 曹元勇: 这会儿，这里大约有三百来个人，全都在读书；可是，如果是这里的每一个人都拥有一位诗人，那绝对是不可能的。（天知道他们拥有什么！）

Comment: Thank you so much 啊啊啊! Did you find these copies online? Can I access them as well?

Comment: @Christoph For copyright reasons can I send you email?

Comment: Thank you so much, I've received your email @user2249675